# How ANN is used for classification?

Tags: neural-network

I am reading about artificial neural networks and it is said that ANN is used for prediction after training with training data. It is also given that ANN is used for classification.

Say I have data consisting of input as ($\theta$, sin($\theta$)) and output as -1 if it is in upper half of sin wave and +1 if it is in lower half. Here is it guaranteed that a trained neural network will always produce output as +1 or -1 (i.e. classify as +1 or -1)? If not, then how is ANN used for classification?

Comment: What specifcally are you asking?

Comment: I want to know if ann will produce output only as +1 or -1 in the mentioned problem if it cannot then how is ann used for classification

Comment: Most of the times classifiers output a number between 0 and 1, the higher the number the higher the chance its classified to that label. If you want a pure -1 to 1 answer, you can search "Hard Limit activation function", maybe it helps

Comment: now say a new data point is there which does not belong to the existing classes now ann output it as somewhere between +1 to -1 and i will use some threshold to classify it to +1 or -1 so thresholding is making it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you have a binary classification problem. I understand what you're asking - you want to know how exactly a network classifies the inputs. Does the network only give (-1, +1) or something else?

Most neural networks don't just say "this is upper or this is lower". The networks would give you a probability distribution [0..1] for each possible class. The most common implementation is the popular [softmax layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). You'd just choose the class with the highest probability as the prediction.

It's also possible to encode your network such that it outputs +1 or -1. In fact, we can always add a layer just after the softmax layer to do exactly that.

If you haven't I recommend you to study logistic regression before tackling neural network.

Comment: neural network gives a single value as output which class probability does it define

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne No it usually doesn't, but you **could** make it like that if you wish. In neutral networks and in fact all ML, we usually talk about probability distributions rather than just a single number.

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne I strongly recommend logistic regression before neutral network.

Answer (score -1):

If you train your network using a large enough dataset and the design of your model is good for your data, the prediction accuracy can get very high. But like all machine learning algorithms, even deep learning algorithms have the limitation of being able to only predict the outcomes of your use case. Deterministic solutions are not possible due to the inherent design properties of ANNs. You can use a tanH activation function to get outputs in the [-1,+1] range. After a  lot of training it is possible that your network will predict correct results in almost all the cases but it again depends on what threshold you set for your outputs.